# primefaces autocomple on datatable

Tags: jsf, autocomplete, primefaces

is it possible to have a datatable with incell editing where one of the fields to be filled is an autocomplete one? I am using primefaces 3.4

```
<p:column headerText="#{label['manufacturer_name']}" style="width:145px">
 <p:cellEditor>
  <f:facet name="output">
     <h:outputText value="#{prod.manufacturer}" style="width:140px" />
   </f:facet>
       <f:facet name="input">
    <p:autoComplete id="acManufacturer" value="#{prod.manufacturer}" completeMethod="#{productBean.manufactures}" style="width:140px" />
    </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

And on the bean side:

```
   public List<String> manufactures(){
    List<String> manufactures = new ArrayList<String>();
    manufactures.add("man2");
    manufactures.add("man1");

    return manufactures;
}
```

My method is never called on the bean.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it with `public List<String> manufactures(String query)`?

Comment: I did. The problem really is that when I click the pencil icon, the object I am trying to populate doesn't yet exist, so when the method is called I get an error

Comment: Is there any solution for this ? I am also facing similar kind of issue <a>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171019/primefaces-pautocomplete-selected-value-repeating-in-next-row-with-datatable</a>