# primefaces p:autocomplete selected value repeating in next row with datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete

I have primefaces datatable which has 4 to 5 input components. One of the input is p:autocomplete. There is a option to add new row through UI, i have added first row later i am trying to add 2nd row whatever value selected in the first row it remains same in the 2nd row. Along with that if i choose different value in the 2nd through autocomplete that value is reflecting for both the rows.

But i would like to retain the value which is selected for first row then i need to retain the 2nd row value differently.

**Note**: I have used p:selectonemenu inorder to show the values from DB, it has 10000+ records it is taking more time. Due to performance issue i had gone for p:autocomplete

Please see the code 
**XHTML code-  LocationDetails.xhtml**

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

 <h:form id="atcs">
<p:dataTable var="atcscirreq" id="atcscirreqtbl"
    value="#{atcsCircuitIdAddressRequestBean.atcsAddressCircuitRequestList}"
    binding="#{atcsCircuitIdAddressRequestBean.dataTable}" lazy="true"     resizableColumns="true">
<p:column id="locn">
<p:autoComplete id="lcnLst" required="true"
    requiredMessage="LocationName is required field"
    converter="locationNameAutoCompleteConverter"
    completeMethod="#{atcsCircuitIdAddressRequestBean.locationNames}"
    var="locn" itemLabel="#{locn.locName}" itemValue="#{locn}"
    value="#{atcsCircuitIdAddressRequestBean.locnInfo}"
    emptyMessage="No Records Found" maxResults="10"
    forceSelection="true">
</p:autoComplete>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton value="Add Another Request" action="#   {atcsCircuitIdAddressRequestBean.addNewRequestData}" update="atcscirreqtbl">

</h:form>
```

**ATCSCircuitIdAddressRequestBean.java**

```
package com.bean.request;

public class ATCSCircuitIdAddressRequestBean {

TblTrackLocationinformation locnInfo = new TblTrackLocationinformation();
List<TblTrackLocationinformation> filteredLocations = new ArrayList<TblTrackLocationinformation>();
private List<TblTrackLocationinformation> atcsAddressCircuitRequestList = new ArrayList<TblTrackLocationinformation>();

public List<TblTrackLocationinformation> locationNames(String name) {
    List<TblTrackLocationinformation> allLocations = service.getAllLocations;
    if (name.trim().equals(""))
        return allLocations;
    for (int i = 0; i < allLocations.size(); i++) {
        TblTrackLocationinformation data = allLocations.get(i);
        if (data.getLocName().toString()
                .contains(name)
                || data.getLocName().toLowerCase()
                        .contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
            filteredLocations.add(data);
        }
    }

    return filteredLocations;
}

public TblTrackLocationinformation getLocnInfo() {
    return locnInfo;
}

public void setLocnInfo(TblTrackLocationinformation locnInfo) {
    this.locnInfo = locnInfo;
}
public void addNewRequestData() {
    TblTrackLocationInformationdata = new TblTrackLocationInformation();
    filteredLocations=new ArrayList<TblTrackLocationinformation>();
    atcsAddressCircuitRequestList.add(data);
}
}
```

**TblTrackLocationInformation.java**

```
package com.bean.request;

public class TblTrackLocationInformation{

private String locName;
private Integer locationId;

public String getLocName() {
    return locName;
}

public void setLocName(String locName) {
    this.locName = locName;
}

public Integer getLocationId() {
    return locationId;
}

public void setLocationId(Integer locationId) {
    this.locationId = locationId;
}
```

}

**LocationNameAutoCompleteConverter.java**

```
package com.bean.request;
@FacesConverter("locationNameAutoCompleteConverter")
public class LocationNameAutoCompleteConverter implements Converter{

LocationInfoDAO locnDao = new LocationInfoDAOImpl();


@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String value) {
    return locnDao.getLocationInfoById(Integer.valueOf(value));
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object value) {
    return String.valueOf(((TblTrackLocationinformation) value)
            .getLocationId());
}
```

}

Specifications of the projects are JSF 2.1, Primefaces 5.0,Servlet 2.5

I have searched many links but i did not get answer. I am checking this for past 2 days.
Please help me out !

Comment: Best thing to do is to create an [mcve], see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks . I have added the required information. Please let me know if you need more information to help me out.

Comment: @BalusC, Thank you. I have updated as per the stackoverflow tags. Please help me out

Comment: JSF 2.1 is an api 'spec' version, not an implementation version (mojarra 2.1.22 is e.g.)

Comment: And it is not an [mcve]... Did you try posting this code as is in a clean new jsf project and run it?

Comment: Yes, i have taken from my project. Please specify what kind of more information u need to help me.

Comment: The behaviour you see is exactely as you designed it. The EL of the value attribute of the autocomplete in each row is bound to the same field in the bean that is in the value attribute of the datatable, not the var attribute.

Comment: @Kukeltje, Thank you . I have tried to use locaitonid in the value attribute that did not help me <pre>value="#{locn.locationId}"</pre>. If you have an idea how to implement. please help me. I have seen BalusC comment and implemented without converter just using itemvalue and value as same that returns integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time, i came to know the solution. We need to know when and how to use List with object and List with String.
Have to use

```
public List<String> locationNames(String name)
```

**instead of**

```
public List<TblTrackLocationinformation> locationNames(String name)
```